# Codemagic Builds not shown in Gitlab CI in group project

Tags: flutter, gitlab-ci, codemagic

I have created a Group in Gitlab to group 2 of my projects. One of them is a flutter project and i added it to Codemagic to run tests on merge requests. Unfortunately Gitlab does not show the job/pipeline when it gets triggered. I have confirmed in Codemagic that the pipeline gets triggered.

I have a different Gitlab project which is not in a group. There the Codemagic pipelines are shown in the Gitlab UI. This is the only difference I can think of.

How can i make Gitlab show the pipelines?